# hgignore - ignore file by specific remote location

Tags: mercurial, hgignore, hgrc

I have checkout from a local mercurial repository and want to make a backup on another repo. but files is too large. it's there any chance to ignoring some directories/files on specific remote?

Comment: This question is not clear to me. Do you want to make a backup? Then use a backup programme and specify which files you want (no) backup of. If you want to make a clone: then you need to clone the whole repository with all files. You can limit it to a single branch, but I doubt that's what you need.

Comment: @planetmaker: i'm sorry, yes it is, i want to add another remote from current repo. but since it size was too large, i need to make exception about some files/directories when push to this remote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Convert Extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ConvertExtension) locally to create a new repository. Using the `--filemap` option, you can exclude specific paths. This will achieve what you want - create subset of your original repository and push that to the remote repo.